# HTML not Linking to CSS Properly

Tags: html, css, node.js

Html not properly loading css file.

Here is my **html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and my **style.css file is in the same folder as my .html file** shown above.

Here is my style.css file:

```
body {
   background: red;     
}
```

When I inspect the "Network" tab of the Chrome developer tools, my style.css file is listed as "pending".

Any idea how to fix this? I have tried disabling AdBlock and clearing the cache.

My server is being run on node.js, not sure if that's relevant here...

Here is my server.js:

```
var http = require("http");

// server sends all requests to router file
var router = require("./router.js");

// set the port #
port = "8080";

// server to listen for requests
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   router.home(request, response);
}).listen(port);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');
```

and here is my router.js file:

```
var renderer = require("./renderer.js");
var url = require("url");
var htmlHeader = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'};

function home(request, response) {

    if (request.url === "/") {

        if (request.method.toLowerCase() === "get") {

            response.writeHead(200, htmlHeader);

            renderer.view("header", {}, response);
            renderer.view("footer", {}, response);

            response.end();
        } 
    }
}

module.exports.home = home;
```

and finally the renderer.js file:

```
// to read contents of [view].html files
var fs = require('fs');

// insert contents into [view].html file
function mergeValues(values, content) {
    // cycle over keys
    for (var key in values) {
        // replace all {{key}} with the value from the values object
        content = content.replace("{{" + key + "}}", values[key]);
    }

    // return merged content
    return content;
}


// handle the view passed as an argument
function view(templateName, values, response) {

    // find the [view].html file in the /views/ folder
    var fileContents = fs.readFileSync('./views/' + templateName + '.html', {encoding: "utf8"});

    // insert values in to the content of the view file
    fileContents = mergeValues(values, fileContents);

    // write out contents to response
    response.write(fileContents);
}

module.exports.view = view;
```

Thanks

Comment: "My server is being run on node.js, not sure if that's relevant here" — Probably. It sounds like the browser is waiting for the server to respond with the stylesheet.

Comment: can you post ur app.js or server.js ?

Comment: I have added in the server.js, router.js, and renderer.js files.

Answer (score 1):

As static files are requested just like any other HTTP request, the server will not locate your css file because you have no route for it.

You will need to add something like:

```
if (request.url === "/style.css") {
    fs.readFile('style.css', function (err, data) {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css', 'Content-Length': data.length});
        response.write(data);
        response.end();
    });
}
```

There are of course better ways to serve static files with module that locates existing files automatically for you. This is ment as a simple answer only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you privileges to access to the css file? Try:

```
chmod 777 style.css
```

Comment: I just read [Fixing answers that recommend “chmod 777”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318885/1529630)